# How can join to table column in single table using linq as full joining

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

In my project,

I have two tables

(1)`Import_detail  table (Date, Description,Parti_Name, Company_name,Amount )` and 
(2)`Export_detail table (Date, Description,Parti_Name, Company_name,Amount )`

and i want to Show this to table detail as Balance sheet in  DataGrid using linq. 
here i am using union for joining to merge column but i don,t know how to get remain Balance

as this sheet.

i am using linq lambda Expression.
please help me.[image]

here Code to  union table

`var query = dm.Import_detail.Select(r => r).Union( dm.Export_detail
 .Select.Select(q => q));`

Comment: Where is your Lambda Expression? Add that too.

Comment: var query = dm.Import_detail.Select(r => r).Union( dm.Export_detail .Select.Select(q => q));

Comment: Edit your question and add your code, Also how your `Debit,Credit, Status, Balance` are calculated? based on what? your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example. may be it is what you want.
I have 3 classes

```
public class Import
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Export
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public decimal creditAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal debitAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal balanceAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

And Select

```
var importList = new List<Import>()
                {
                    new Import{date = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-02"), amount = 10000},
                    new Import{date = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-25"), amount = 6000}
                };

                var exportList = new List<Export>()
                {
                    new Export{date = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-05"), amount = 500},
                    new Export{date = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-10"), amount = 1000},
                    new Export{date = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-11"), amount = 1500},
                    new Export{date = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-15"), amount = 4000},
                    new Export{date = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-28"), amount = 5000}
                };


                var temp = importList.Select(c => new Result { date = c.date, debitAmount = c.amount, creditAmount = 0, balanceAmount = 0 }).Union(
                    exportList.Select(c => new Result { date = c.date, debitAmount = 0, creditAmount = c.amount, balanceAmount = 0 })).GroupBy(c => c.date).Select(c => new Result { date = c.Key, creditAmount = c.Sum(g => g.creditAmount), debitAmount = c.Sum(g => g.debitAmount) }).OrderBy(c => c.date).ToList();

                foreach (var item in temp)
                    item.balanceAmount = temp.Where(c => c.date < item.date).OrderByDescending(c => c.date).Select(c => c.balanceAmount).FirstOrDefault() + item.debitAmount - item.creditAmount;
```

Results:

```
debitAmount  creditAmount balanceAmount
10000        0            10000
0            500          9500
0            1000         8500
0            1500         7000
0            4000         3000
6000         0            9000 
0            5000         4000
```